# Declare structure in header file

Tags: c, declaration

I have type `fifo_t` definition in my **fifo.c** file like below. What should be declaration of this type in the header file **fifo.h**? I want to make the contents of this structure was known only within the file **fifo.c**. Additionally, I do not want to be able to create instance of this structure through `struct struct_name var;`. Only valid way should be `fifo_t var;`

```
typedef struct {
    uint8_t *buffer,
    uint8_t indexRead,
    uint8_t indexWrite,
    uint8_t used,
    uint8_t size
} fifo_t;
```

Comment: You can't do this with the raw `struct` itself. You could make a `typedef` for an opaque _pointer_ to the `struct`? Is that acceptable? You can't actually declare `fifo_t var;` in other code without the full struct definition because the other code wouldn't have the information to set aside enough memory to hold it.

Comment: If you want to have the structure only be known in a specific source file, why not simply define it in the source file instead of the header file?

Comment: Optionally if you need the structure in just a few source files, but not most of them, then make a new "private" header (e.g. `fifo_private.h`) file that contains this structure.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: Typedef'ing pointers is a bad idea.

Comment: @Olaf: When they're opaque handles to data that is only created, destroyed, and used by API functions? Not so much. When the pointer isn't logically a pointer, and users have no direct access to the data it refers to, it's fine to obscure its identity as a pointer.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: Well, in C you can hardly avoid getting in touch with the semantics. If you need a handle, better pass a `uintptr_t` or a true handle so you can validate its value (more or less).

Answer (score 4):

If you want to only be able to pass pointers to `fifo_t` around, then you can only forward-declare it in the header file. However, `typedef` for unnamed structs is only valid when you're defining the content of the struct. So if you don't want `struct fifo_t var;` to compile, you'll have to resort to some counter-intuitive name, maybe something like `fifo_t_`. For example:

```
typedef struct fifo_t_ fifo_t;
void fifo_use(fifo_t*); // ok, just uses pointer
```

And then in the `.c` file, do (and please note that using comma to separate members isn't valid syntax):

```
struct fifo_t_ {
    uint8_t *buffer;
    uint8_t indexRead;
    uint8_t indexWrite;
    uint8_t used;
    uint8_t size;
};

void fifo_use(fifo_t* f) {
    f->indexRead = 1;
}
```

Also, note that `fifo_t var;` won't work because you need to know the size of the struct in order to allocate space for it. What you *could* do, is use pointers internally, in a way that's transparent to the user:

```
// in .h file:

typedef struct fifo_t_* fifo_t;

void fifo_init(fifo_t*);
void fifo_free(fifo_t);
void fifo_use(fifo_t);

// in .c file:

struct fifo_t_{
    uint8_t *buffer;
    uint8_t indexRead;
    uint8_t indexWrite;
    uint8_t used;
    uint8_t size;
};

void fifo_init(fifo_t* f) {
    *f = (fifo_t)malloc(sizeof(struct fifo_t_));
}

void fifo_free(fifo_t f) {
    free(f);
}

void fifo_use(fifo_t f) {
    f->indexRead = 1;
}


// somewhere else

int main() {
    fifo_t fifo;
    fifo_init(&fifo);
    fifo_use(fifo);
    fifo_free(fifo);
}
```

Comment: Maybe better to have `typedef void* fifo_t;` instead of abscurate `struct` pointer.

Comment: @LPs The problem with that is that then you can pass in anything, and you lose some degree of type safety.

Comment: No need for the trailing underscore in the structure name, structure names live in a separate namespace together with unions. So e.g. `typedef struct fifo_t fifo_t;` would work just fine. I would also advice against declaring a type-alias as a pointer. If a pointer is needed then it's better to make it explicit (the way `FILE*` is used), it will be easier to remember if a variable is a pointer if it's explicitly declared as a pointer.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Roger; note he asked for `struct fifo_t my_var;` not to compile. I don't know why, but that's what he asked for.

Comment: Probably I need coffee, but for me this solution cannot work. If OP try to define a fifo_t var and use it into a different file than the one where the struct is defined compiler will show error: _dereferencing pointer to incomplete.._ Am I wrong?

Comment: @LPs :) `fifo_t var;` will do `struct fifo_t_* var;` since it's forward-declared, it's okay. Dereferencing error will only happen if you then do `fifo_t->something`. But the point is that you're only supposed to use it via functions.

Comment: Yes, but you are not hiding, as OP I think is trying to do, the struct members. So you can write `var->indexRead=1`, and compiler will trigger an error. In this vision I wrote that was better, for this case, to typedef a `void *`. BTW I trust that `typedef`ing pointers is always the worst solution.

Comment: @LPs It's indeed hidden; that's why the dereference errors out. It's known only within the translation unit that defines the actual struct. Also, it's just as easy to not `typedef` it to a pointer, and then just use `fifo_t*` whenever you want to have a variable. That's the first proposed solution here.

Answer (score 0):

you can't hide the content of `fifo_t` if you want to be able to create it on stack like `fifo_t var;` because the `sizeof(fifo_t)` is unknown

You may do forvard declaration of `fifo_t` in header: `struct fifo_t;`. In other files you'll be able to create poiners to `fifo_t` and work with them using functions that should be &implemented in fifo.c

```
fifo_t *var;
create(&var);
do_work(var);
destroy(var);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do want to make definition of the struct in **fifo.h** this is the way to go:

**fifo.h**

```
... 
#ifdef FIFO
 typedef struct {
    uint8_t *buffer,
    uint8_t indexRead,
    uint8_t indexWrite,
    uint8_t used,
    uint8_t size
} fifo_t;
#else
...
#endif
...
```

**fifo.c**

```
#define FIFO
#include "fifo.h"
...
```

so **fifo.h** still could be include in other source files but the struct type is hide, it's only visible with **fifo.c**